# GPS gets wrong Position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, localization, gps, cllocationmanager

basicly the Location-Controller in my App works. But if it runs over a long time, it gets wrong Positions without recognizing it. I think the gps-buffer overflows or kind of that.

here's my code for the didUpdate-Event

`- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {`

```
//nonvalid
if (signbit(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy))
    return;

//0.0 is no valid location here
if ((abs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude) < 1.0e-05) || (abs(newLocation.coordinate.longitude) < 1.0e-05))
    return;

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > DBL_MAX)
    return;


@synchronized(self)
{
    currentCoordinate.latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    currentCoordinate.longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
}
```

}

is it possible to flush the location buffer? 
or to control the Position with the value from triangulating?

Comment: You don't have to include "iPhone" in the title, as long as you add the tag "iphone". :)

Comment: How long a time are you talking about? It seems very unlikely that this won't have been tested thoroughly by Apple ;)

Answer (score 1):

You should also test the age of your location data. This is the closest thing to flushing the cache (which is not possible). Check the `timestamp` property and reject the update if it's too old.

```
// check that the location data isn't older than 60 seconds
if ([newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] < [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - 60) {
    return;
}
```